# NTP client for redpitaya

Tags: redpitaya

The clock is set at 1 January 1970 0:00:42 PM UTC on each redpitaya reboot, and I can change it with the command example: date-s 2014.03.09-08:30

Is it possible to set up a NTP client on redpitaya?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In release 0.90, the root filesystem of Red Pitaya Linux OS is staged - a modified ramdisk from Xilinx Linux 14.6 release.

As part of the latest Red Pitaya developments on GitHub, this filesystem/ramdisk is built from sources using buildroot which is configurable via [Red Pitaya buildroot configuration file](https://github.com/RedPitaya/RedPitaya/blob/master/OS/buildroot/config) where several additions, including the NTP client, can be added.

In addition to this, the "connman" network connection manager has been added, primarily for Ethernet hotplug functionality, but it has an NTP client integrated and functional, provided your DHCP server replies with a timeserver option (option 42 as specified in RFC 2132).
You can get the latest builds with "connman" included [here](http://redpitaya.com/archives/devel/).

Comment: Thanks, Confirms that the latest development version 0.91-314 solve my ntp issues. NTP also work great with wifi connected redpitaya with recommended Edimax EW7811U USB adapter.