# NTPClient not working even after Redpitaya OS Rebuild

Tags: ntp, busybox, ntpd, redpitaya

I am trying to run NTPD service on redpitaya. I followed this blog ([NTP client for redpitaya](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22280263/ntp-client-for-redpitaya)) and built the kernel from scratch using this link: http://wiki.redpitaya.com/index.php?title=Red_Pitaya_OS.

But even after fresh build with config files having entry 'BR2_PACKAGE_NTP=y' in config file of build root and 'CONFIG_NTPD=y' & 'CONFIG_FEATURE_NTPD_SERVER =y' in busy box.config, it is still not working. Some other features like wget and * started working but not the required NTPD service. Kindly help me in rectifying this issue.

Comment: Attach the ps command output and any other debugging that you might have done.

Comment: @Arpith Please find below link to screenshot of PS command.

Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5l084lnzachkgee/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-12%20at%2013.31.54.png?dl=0

Comment: I do not see ntpd running on your system. Did you enable it in services?

Comment: I tried but it shows service not found. Link: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x9jaus12p6zp001/Screen%20Shot%202015-06-12%20at%2014.39.39.png?dl=0

Problem I am facing is ntp client is not available in busy box and I am not able to install third party ntp client due to limited options in redpitaya busy box.

Comment: Busy box doesnt give ntpd by default. Have you cross compiled and ported the ntpd binary for your target?

Comment: Yes I did as per instructions in given on link above.

Comment: Where is the binary on your filesystem?

Comment: I have enabled NTP in config file but I am not sure whether including path of NTP binary will help as other packages are included by assigning 'y' in config file.

Comment: I meant to say if your ntpd binary is in /usr/bin/ntpd then just run "/usr/bin/ntpd" from the shell. If this ends with a successful timesync then you need to add this command in the init or overlay scripts